# ArrayCollection removing sort

Tags: apache-flex

After applying a numeric sort to my dataprovider(Array Collection), I can not reorder the items via a tilelist. Do I need to remove the sort from the arrayCollection. If so, is it just a case of setting collection.sort = null ?

```
var sortField:SortField=new SortField();
sortField.name="order";
sortField.numeric=true;
var sort:Sort=new Sort();
sort.fields=[sortField];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the sort to null should indeed remove the sort for the collection. You might need to do an optional refresh().

Comment: Hum... actually, when I set `sort = null` and try to edit the `ArrayCollection` I get an exception. Unless I do call `ArrayCollection.refresh()` but when I do this, even though `sort` is `null`, the data is sorted. I'm stuck :p

Comment: I get the same behavior as you @nununo. Did you find out what was happening?

Comment: Ya, same here. I just ended up sorting the ArrayCollection myself. Lame.

Comment: Setting the sort to null and then doing a refresh worked for me.  Since sort is now set as null, the collection will stay in the order it was last sorted.  This helped fix a problem where a datagrid drag&drop was not working because I'd left the original sort on the ArrayCollection DataProvider.  After setting it to null and refreshing I'm back in business.

Answer (score 1):

[Source](http://kuriakosejacobthomas.blogspot.com/2009/10/adobe-flex-sorting-arraycolleciton-by.html)

> Adobe Flex - Sorting an ArrayCollection by Date
>
> ```
> /**
> * @params data:Array
> * @return dataCollection:Array
> **/
> private function orderByPeriod(data:Array):Array
> {
>  var dataCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(data);//Convert Array to ArrayCollection to perform sort function
>
>  var dataSortField:SortField = new SortField();
>  dataSortField.name = "period"; //Assign the sort field to the field that holds the date string
>
>  var numericDataSort:Sort = new Sort();
>  numericDataSort.fields = [dataSortField];
>  dataCollection.sort = numericDataSort;
>  dataCollection.refresh();
>  return dataCollection.toArray();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I got caught with this problem too, I found your question, and I still didnt get it solved like Christophe suggested.

After suffering with this for a while, I discovered one way to avoid the problems you mentioned.

**Simply use an auxiliary ArrayCollection to do the sort**. Anyway your Sort instance seems to be temporary (you want to through it away), so why not use a temporary ArrayCollection?

Here's how my code looked like:

```
// myArrayCollection is the one to sort

// Create the sorter
var alphabeticSort:ISort = new Sort();
var sortfieldFirstName:ISortField = new SortField("firstName",true);
var sortfieldLastName:ISortField = new SortField("lastName",true);
alphabeticSort.fields = [sortfieldFirstName, sortfieldLastName];

// Copy myArrayCollection to aux
var aux:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
while (myArrayCollection.length > 0) {
    aux.addItem(myArrayCollection.removeItemAt(0));
}

// Sort the aux
var previousSort:ISort = aux.sort;
aux.sort = alphabeticSort;
aux.refresh();
aux.sort = previousSort;

// Copy aux to myArrayCollection
var auxLength:int = aux.length;
while (auxLength > 0) {
    myArrayCollection.addItemAt(aux.removeItemAt(auxLength - 1), 0);
    auxLength--;
}
```

It's not the neatest code, it has some weird hacks like auxLength instead of aux.length (this one gave me -1 array range exception), but at least it solved my problem.