# AS3: Error #1006: value is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, date, time

I got piece of code:

```
trace((array[0][0]));
trace((array[0][0] is Date));
trace((array[0][0] as Date).time());
```

and this is my output:

```
Fri Aug 9 12:10:00 GMT+0200 2013
true
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
    ...
```

I'm confused. How can I fix this?

*//edit:*
Oh, it should be

```
trace((array[0][0] as Date).time);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trace((array[0][0] as Date).getTime());
```

OR

```
trace((array[0][0] as Date).time);
```

The error says that "time" is not a function of class Date - it is not, it's a property. But there is a function `getTime()` which might be what you seek.

[Date class manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html)

Answer (score 0):

An refresh() call after setting `sort` to `null` made this RTE go away for me.

This solution was originally suggested at [ArrayCollection removing sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224853/arraycollection-removing-sort) topic