# as3 TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function, on addItem

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have the following code

```
_data.sort = null;
agentRow=new Object();
agentRow.AgentID=agentId;
_data.addItem(agentRow);
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/getFilteredItemIndex()
at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/addItemsToView()
at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/listChangeHandler()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.collections::ArrayList/internalDispatchEvent()
at mx.collections::ArrayList/addItemAt()
at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/addItemAt()
at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/addItem()
at com.informiam.frontlineAdvisor.dashboard.model::TeamMetricAggregator/merge()
at com.informiam.frontlineAdvisor.dashboard.controller::AdvisorController/mergeTeamViewData()
at com.informiam.frontlineAdvisor.dashboard.view.components::TeamView/mergeMetricsResult()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.rpc::AbstractOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()
at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()
at mx.rpc::Responder/result()
at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()
at NetConnectionMessageResponder/resultHandler()
at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/result()
```

_data is an 
`ArrayCollection`

If remove the line `_data.sort = null;` then the error is gone, but I need this line.

I have already looked at [AS3: Error #1006: value is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18144398/3024116)

Comment: @LDMS I prefer to the sort field nulled. Is this not allowed?

Comment: Testing this right now, getting a different error that is semi related so it will be a while before I can confirm

Comment: @LDMS if you submi ur comment as an answer I will select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem logical that the issue is `null` not being an acceptable value for the sort property.  While I don't have experience with most of the flex components (including this one), I imaging doing one of the following would rectify your issue:

a. Don't assign any value to the sort property (I would assume this would be the equivalent of no sorting)

OR

b. Assign `new Sort()` instead of `null` to your `_data.sort` property.

Answer (score -1):

```
_data.sort = null;
_data.refresh();
agentRow=new Object();
agentRow.AgentID=agentId;
_data.addItem(agentRow);
```